# Android: Expanded SearchView aligns right

Tags: android, android-actionbar, alignment, toolbar, searchview

In my app I want to create a searchview within an actionbar. I've used the following code.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/autocomplete_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/search_light"
      android:title="@string/what_form_edit_text"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" /></menu>
```

With this code a search icons shows up in my activity. After clicking this icon the search view expands and aligns on the left side of my actionbar (the title is gone).

[image]

Now I want to achieve this behaviour when automatically expanding the searchview. I tried to change the values of showAsAction into "always" instead of "ifRoom|collapseActionView", but it's not working. The searchview gets expanded, but is aligned on the right side of the actionbar. Is there any way I am missing to align the searchview on the left side (without implementing my own toolbar and place the searchview within?). Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
 app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

It should fix your issue.